# Search inside results object - Python, BeatifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get some informations in a site, put it in a list and exporting this list to csv.
This is an part of the site, it repeats several times.

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="Aclimação">
</a>
</div>
Clique na imagem para ampliar
</div>
<div class="colInfos">
<h4>Aclimação</h4>
<div class="addressInfo">
Rua Muniz de Souza, 1110<br>
Aclimação - São Paulo - SP<br>
01534-001<br>
<br>
(11) 3208-3418 / 2639-0173<br>
<a href="mailto:aclimacao.sp@escolas.com.br">aclimacao.sp@escolas.com.br</a><br>
```

I want to get the image link, name (h4), address(inside addressInfo, each br should be an separated item in a list) and email of each school (a href mailto:) in this site and export to s csv file. This is how I'm trying. But there is a problem, because I don't know how to search inside the results object 'endereco' How can I do this?
This is my code:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


url = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.fisk.com.br/unidades?pais=1&uf=&rg=&cid=&ba=&un=")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
#nomes = soup.findAll('h4')

dados = []
i = 1

for endereco in enderecos:
    text = ''.join(endereco.findAll(???)) **<- how an I search the br's inside this?**
    dados[i] = text.encode('utf-8').strip()
    i = i +     

enderecos = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'colInfos'})
```

Answer (score 0):

It really works fine. All you have to do is replace

```
dados = []
i = 1

for endereco in enderecos:
    text = ''.join(endereco.findAll(text=True))
    dados[i] = text.encode('utf-8').strip()
    i = i +     

enderecos = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'colInfos'})
```

with

```
dados = []

enderecos = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'colInfos'})

for endereco in enderecos:
    text = ''.join(endereco.findAll(text=True))
    dados.append(text.encode('utf-8').strip())
print dados
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I was not very clear. I edited my question, can you see it again? What should i use in text instead of text=True to find the br tags inside it?